# Selecting direct descendent not working

Tags: jquery, css

http://jsfiddle.net/fVtyP/

```
$('.menu > li a').css('background-color', 'red');
```

or

```
$('.menu > li').find('a').css('background-color', 'red');
```

I'd like to only select the direct descendent but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `$('.menu > li > a')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/fVtyP/3/

`$('.menu > li > a').css('background-color', 'red');` // select a element direct descendent of li direct descendent of element with class menu

`$('.menu > li').children('a').css('background-color', 'red');` // select all children of type anchor inside an li direct descendant of an element with class menu

Answer (score 1):

Technically, by your layout, all of the `<a>` elements are children of an `<li>`. You need to directly select twice:

```
$('.menu > li > a').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 1):

With method `.children()` you can select the first child level of your selector

try this:

```
$('.menu > li').children('a').css('background-color', 'red');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fVtyP/1/)